# Visual Studio 2015 - missing 64 bit compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Currently I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 on a 32-Bit computer and create 32-bit applications in C++/CLI.

As far as I remember one could choose between creating 32 and 64-Bit applications in previous Visual Studio versions, if one has installed the 64-Bit compiler too.

Today I was trying to get the same functionality out of the 2015's version of Visual Studio, but I'm not able to find any option to install the 64-Bit compiler.

In the compiler-settings I can only choose between ARM and 32-Bit (no 64-Bit, no "any platform"). Running the Visual Studio Setup from the Windows system preferences also shows no possibility to install the 64-Bit compiler (or maybe i just don't know what to install).

**QUESTION: How can I install the 64-Bit C++ compiler for Visual Studio 2015 on a 32-Bit computer?**

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's no such term as 64 or 32-bit compiler: any compiler should be able to compile for 32- and 64-bit

Comment: [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

Comment: As far as I remember I had to install an compiler in previous versions of VS (as mentioned above). Maybe you are wright, but I'd like to have the "Any Platform" possibility back so that i can create apps for 64-bit on my 32-bit machine.

Comment: @GSerg Thank's that's what i was looking for. Do you know if there is still the possibility to create an app for 32 and 64-bit platforms, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: [Visual C++ Tools and Templates in Visual Studio Editions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@GSerg gave the aswer I needed in his first comment - thank you for your help!

The compiler seems to be installed by default. I just wasn't able to find the way to set the platform.

Comment: If you downvote a question and answer, please tell me why - or I will never write a better one ;-)